# Python Requests Performance is low

Tags: python, django, performance, python-requests

I am developing an RestAPI, and there is a part where I need to take a file from request, pass it to the Microsoft Cognitive Service and response back some information.

Apart from the details of implementation, my problem is with the performance of the Python requests module. The total time of the response was around 12 seconds on average, so I dig a little bit of my code and found out that the requests module of Python is actually uploading the file at slow rate. And the interesting part is that file is not big at all. The size of the file that I use for the requests is exactly 201 Kb.

Specifically talking about the details of the performance, post request takes around 6-7 seconds in general. Whereas, the same request-response time is 1.5 seconds on average, when I use Postman to make request. This is a huge gap, right? The request is also so simple, it is just passing the file with a required header.

You can find the code below.

```
def identification(identification_profile_ids, file, short_audio=True):
headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': SUBSCRIPTION_KEY,
}

url = _BASE_URI + '/spid/v1.0/identify?identificationProfileIds={}&shortAudio={}'.format(identification_profile_ids,
                                                                                         short_audio)

response = requests.post(url, data=file, headers=headers)

return response
```

Please do not hesitate to ask me further question. Sorry in advance for the parts that I forgot to mention!

Thanks!

Comment: What is `file`?  Is it the file in-memory, is it the filename or is it a file stream?

Comment: Also, was there a reason you weren’t specifying `application/octet-stream` as the `Content-type` header?

Comment: File is taken from the incoming request. It is not in-memory file, or filename. It is file-stream @2ps. And there is no reason not to do why. I can give it a try I suppose.

Comment: Well I tried to add but Microsoft, I guess, might have problem with the content-type header since it started to return me different headers at the time I add content-type application/octet-stream header @2ps